# Android and FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments

With this code from my Fragment class:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
```

I got null. Why? I found in android doc that sentence:

> Note that this will be non-null slightly before getActivity(), during the time from when the fragment is placed in a FragmentTransaction until it is committed and attached to its activity.

But I don't understand it at all. What to do to not get that null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your activity should be an instance of FragmentActivity and call getFragmentManager() from here

Comment: It is an instance of FragmentActivity. This code is inside Fragment class.

Comment: Ok, it looks like working, but wondering why it was happened that at first opening it works ok, but after chenging fragment and getting back, it stops to work. After digging I've noticed that FragmentPagerAdapter, in which was this fragment, was restoring it's state from BackStack. Still wonder why.. Because of that no getItem() method was called and so there was no reference to fragment that was in Activity's container, but to some newly created Fragment without it's activity.. Weird, rly. Anyway, thanks for help.